# MutipleCheckBox saving to Database with Django

Tags: python, database, django

I'm trying to find some kind of canonical reference for this problem where I use the follow type model:

```
class MyPreferencesForm(forms.Form):
    MyGenderPref = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

and the view

```
def GoPreferences(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = MyPreferencesForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            model_instance = f.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.save()
            f.save_m2m()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        f = MyPreferencesForm()

    return render(request, "mypreferences.html", {'form': f})
```

However I tried to follow what I thought was sensible and include the many to many. But I still cannot make this work. My error is the following:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'MyPreferencesForm' object has no attribute 'save'
```

The error emanates from line containing `model_instance = f.save(commit=False)`

Answer (score 2):

`save` is available only for forms inherited from `ModelForm` objects. Here, you are inheriting form `forms.Form` Hence the error.

Either inherit the form from `forms.ModelForm` and specify a `Meta` attribute

```
class MyPreferencesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    MyGenderPref = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

You can read more on [`ModelForm`s here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) - You might have to modify your form slightly based on your specific requirements.

OR

```
 model_instance = MyModel.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data) #manage manually
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Either inherit the form from forms.ModelForm and specify a Meta attribute" have you got any examples?

Answer (score 0):

If your m2m tables in your models.py uses `through` then you'll need to manage the saving manually using object.create and you can't use save_m2m() or save()